# Converting a black and white image to List of Lists ( 0, 1) using Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, binary, maze

I am creating a program that solves mazes using the Turtle module in Python, to draw it i use Lists of Lists in order to represent columns and its spaces through List[y][x]. What would be the optimal way to convert an image like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI3Fi.jpg) into a List of Lists with binary values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to loop through the pixels of the image to check if they are black or white. You don't need to check all of them, to optimize the process, you can check one pixel for each block and skip the rest, in this way, rather than check 159.201 pixels (399 x 399, the size of the image), you only check 441‬ pixels (21 x 21, the number of blocks)

[image]

Here is an example of how you can read the maze:

```py
from PIL import Image

BLOCK_SIZE = 19

im = Image.open('maze.jpg')
pixels = im.load()
width, height = im.size
offset = int(BLOCK_SIZE / 2)

maze = [
  [
    int(pixels[x + offset, y + offset][0] < 125)
    for y in range(0, height, BLOCK_SIZE)
  ]
  for x in range(0, width, BLOCK_SIZE)
]
```

If you print the content of `maze` after the process with:

```py
for y in range(height / BLOCK_SIZE):
  for x in range(width / BLOCK_SIZE):
    print(maze[x][y]),
  print('')
```

this is what you obtain:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

A few notes about the code:

```py
int(pixels[x + offset, y + offset][0] < 125)
```

This takes a pixel (`pixels[x + offset, y + offset]`) from the block (x, y) and from it extracts the first channel of the RGB color, since it can be either black or white, all the 3 channels should have the same value (eg: `(0, 0, 0)` for black or `(255, 255, 255)` for white), but the image is not perfect, some colors are actually gray, that's why rather then checking for a specific value, I used `< 125` to separate black blocks from white blocks.

The purpose of the `offset` is to take the pixel in the center of each block, this is useful because, again, the image is not perfect, and pixels on the border of the block are less reliable

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Exactly what I was looking for, my question is, how did you manage to get the box size?

Comment: `block width = image width / maze columns = 399 / 21 = 19`, `block height = image height / maze rows = 399 / 21 = 19` block size: `19x19`